# iphone snow falling effect

Tags: iphone, ipad

i have been following
[apps](https://web.archive.org/web/20130815165715/http://appsamuck.com/day9.html)
snowfall tutorial, but i am getting some issue in iOS 5, something like [this](http://appsamuck.com/images/day9_ScreenShot.jpg)
[image]
<sub>(source: [appsamuck.com](http://appsamuck.com/images/day9_ScreenShot.jpg))</sub>

-

```
 (void)onAnimationComplete:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {

    UIImageView *flakeView = context;
```

****this is where the issue is: implicit conversion of a non objective c pointer type 'void *' to 'UIimageview' is disallowed when using ARC

Please suggest, how can I solve this problem.

Regards

[image]

Comment: use `UIImageView *flakeView = (__bridge UIImageView *)context;`. Not an answer because I can't explain why ^^

Comment: Hello Shishir, did you intend to attach an additional image to your posting?  The "[enter image description here]" bit gives it away.  :-)

Comment: sry for the formating. i was trying to attach my screenshot of my code.let me try again

Comment: @flunchtpunkt that worked. cool. i have one more place, where i am getting the same thing."//UIImageView* flakeView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:flakeImage];" how should i convert this?[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:flakeView];

Comment: I'd highly recommend replacing the above code with UIView's blocks-based implementation of animations, because that eliminates the need to pass in a bridged value for the context. As I comment below, the straight bridging opens you up to potential crashes if the context object is deallocated before the callback is triggered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Expanding on @fluchtpunkt 's comment which should really have been an answer ;)

ARC works by determining, at compile time, if the objects are needed or not - it then works out your retain/release for you.

If you pass an object as `(void *)` the compiler cannot work out that it has to retain this object so it might get released before you use it.

The `__bridge` explicitly tells the compiler that you are passing a 'real' object but using a `void *` to do it.

However, there might be a risk of a memory leak if you don't tell the compiler somewhere else that you are done with the object :)

Take a look at [http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/*index.html*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html) and search for '_bridge' to see more details.

Comment: In this case, I don't know if it's a leak I'd be worried about, but a crash if the bridged object went away before it was used by the callback. The straight bridge won't cause it to be retained by the callback, so it could be deallocated at some point in the meantime.

Comment: THen use `__bridge_retain` instead - that article is dull but useful ;)